# specify a default value to a child class in grails

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm, default-value

I was wondering if it is possible to assign a default value to a variable in a child class when it is defined in the parent class.

For the sake of an example, I'll take the environment of a camping site (couldn't think of a better one)

We have a lodging class (parent). A lodging can be either a tent site, a mobile home, chalets...etc. Only the tent site doesn't have a patio (by default). The other may or may not have one and also have some special specification that a tent site doesn't (dishes, covers...etc).

Now...I'm lazy and prefer to put the variable patio (boolean) in the lodging class and then, declare in the tent class patio has false by default.
Or should I create a patio variable in every child class ?

```
class Lodging{
    String description
    int capacity
    Boolean patio
}

class Tent extends Lodging{
    static mapping = {
        patio defaultValue: false
    }
}
```

When I create a new Tent instance, the mapping rules will be followed ? Or will it throw me an error that it doesn't recognize the variable ?

I haven't tried anything, but it crossed my mind and didn't manage to get the answer from the grails doc (or here).
Hope my explanations and question were understandable :)

Comment: So you haven't even tried this to see if it works?

Comment: Write a test to see if it works. And let us know :)

Comment: And the award for least helpful comments ever goes to...

Answer (score 0):

you can use an initializing block in child classes like:

```
class Lodging{
    String description
    int capacity
    Boolean patio
}

class Tent extends Lodging{
    static mapping = {
        patio defaultValue: false
    };
    {
        patio = false
    }

}
```

Please note the semi-colon that has to be there before the initializing block